# Transition for different colors of SVG referenced with <use /> not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, css-transitions

I'm trying to do CSS transition for two different colors of a SVG which is referenced by using `<use />`.

My approach is using CSS custom properties to define the colors of `fill` and set the transition declarations for `fill` on the child elements (`<path>` and `<polygon>`) of SVG.

It works on Firefox, but not on Chrome. Any solution for Chrome?

```css
.icon-right-chevron {
    --circle: gold;
    --chevron: orange;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    }

.icon-right-chevron:hover {
    --circle: green;
    --chevron: blue;
    }
```

```html
<svg style="position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" aria-hidden="true">
    <symbol id="icon-right-chevron" viewBox="0 0 485 485" fill="none">
        <path fill="var(--circle)" style="transition: fill 1s;" d="M413.974,71.026C368.171,25.225,307.274,0,242.5,0S116.829,25.225,71.026,71.026C25.225,116.829,0,177.726,0,242.5 s25.225,125.671,71.026,171.474C116.829,459.775,177.726,485,242.5,485s125.671-25.225,171.474-71.026 C459.775,368.171,485,307.274,485,242.5S459.775,116.829,413.974,71.026z M242.5,455C125.327,455,30,359.673,30,242.5 S125.327,30,242.5,30S455,125.327,455,242.5S359.673,455,242.5,455z" />
        <polygon fill="var(--chevron)" style="transition: fill 1s;" points="193.228,135.589 299.791,242.5 193.228,349.411 214.476,370.589 342.148,242.5 214.476,114.411" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-right-chevron"><use xlink:href="#icon-right-chevron" /></svg>
```

Attribution: Icon made by [Smashicons](https://smashicons.com/) from [www.flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG CSS transition not working on \`use\` element (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969261/svg-css-transition-not-working-on-use-element-chrome)

Comment: @TobiasBuschor Thanks. However, I just tested it and it does not work for me. I guess the reason is that my situation requires the transitions of two colors and the suggestion only works for the transition of one color.