# SVG CSS transition not working on `use` element (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, css-transitions

I'm unable to get a CSS transition to work on a `use` element inside of an SVG.

It works on the original SVG, but not when I use `use`. See below.

This appears to be Chrome specific (both examples work in FF).

```css
.stretched-rect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.stretched-rect svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.stretched-rect {
  --fill-color: red;
}
.stretched-rect:hover {
  --fill-color: blue;
}
```

```html
  Example with original svg (this works):
  <div class="stretched-rect">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="100" height="100" rx="15" style="fill: var(--fill-color); transition: 1s fill;"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  <!-- Define SVG, so we can use it with `use` -->
  <svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="svg-rect" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="100" height="100" rx="15" style="fill: var(--fill-color); transition: 1s fill;"/>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  
  Example using "use" (this does not work):
  <div class="stretched-rect">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#svg-rect"/></svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works in Mozilla.

Comment: Seems to work OK for me on Firefox. Report it as a bug on the bugtracker of whatever browser you're using.

Comment: Mind firing up Chrome and telling me if it works or not? I can confirm this example does work in FF, though my actual use case does not. I'll investigate further and see if I can replicate brokeness in FF.

Comment: Got it working in FF as well. I'll submit a bug. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to make it work: delete the style from the symbol's rect and paste it to the `<use>` element: `<use xlink:href="#svg-rect" style="fill: var(--fill-color); transition: 1s fill;"/>`

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for the workaround. If you submit an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I don't have an answer as this is a "bug" but this is a cool question, well narrowed down and all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by others, **this appears to be a bug in Chrome**. See below for workaround.

As I've commented: instead of styling the rect in the symbol you can apply the styles to the use element:
Delete the style from the symbol's rect and paste it to the use element:

```css
.stretched-rect {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.stretched-rect svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.stretched-rect {
  --fill-color: red;
}
.stretched-rect:hover {
  --fill-color: blue;
}
```

```html
Example with original svg (this works):
  <div class="stretched-rect">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="100" height="100" rx="15" style="fill: var(--fill-color); transition: 1s fill;"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  <!-- Define SVG, so we can use it with `use` -->
  <svg style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="svg-rect" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="100" height="100" rx="15" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  
  Example using "use" (this is working now):
  <div class="stretched-rect">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#svg-rect" style="fill: var(--fill-color); transition: 1s fill;"/></svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can also style the `use` tag in CSS.  Eg: `.stretched-rect use { fill: red; transition: 1s fill; }`

Comment: This bug and workaround breaks my existing program which makes use of use statements referencing another inline svg with path. The inline svg with path has class that is dynamically changed by animation, etc. Any idea when this bug will be fixed!